# Subject-verb agreement. Subject is plural, but not really

Tags: verb-agreement

Once again I have a line that I wrote for another site that has me a bit bugged.

> Months in the freezer is going to pretty much eliminate any risk of consuming a live parasite.

*Months* is obviously plural, but I'm pretty sure that the line is correct as written.

How?

Or potentially, why not?

Comment: 'Months' here signifies 'a period of several months,' singular. QED.

Comment: What bugs me a bit is the phrase *has me (a bit) bugged.* I am [pretty sure](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Has+me+bugged%2Cbugs+me&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbugs%20me%3B%2Cc0) this is not idiomatic.

Comment: @CarSmack Hmmm...phrasing of corn-fed Iowa girls?

Comment: Sorry @Jolenealaska, my intent was to express my own dis-ease, not to impugn your usage. It had me stressed a bit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence, although the time period is a plural of months, we are talking about the single time period.

*Three months in the freezer* is a noun phrase, and because it is one time period it is singular, so using *is* is the correct. This is the same reason that we say *ten years is a long time to wait* instead of *ten years are a long time to wait* - ten years is a single time period.

Answer (score 1):

> Months in the freezer is going to pretty much eliminate any risk of consuming a live parasite

**If** *months* is considered to be a single period of time, then it takes a singular verb, just as the following often do:

*Three years* in prison is too long.

*Seven seconds* was too long to wait.

*Months and months and months* in the fridge is pretty much going to eliminate any risk...

If *months* are considered as separate units of time, you can use *are.*

Comment: He beat you by *this much* :) Thanks though.

Comment: @Jolenealaska No problem, it's not a race :) but see my "intrusive" comment to your OP